# why I get ENONET: no such file or directory when the file exists? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a crash course on YouTube before I dive deeper into React and NodeJs.
Im trying to check the url from the code and display the right page.
so if the url ends with `'/about'` I will display the about html.
the problem is that it's not displaying the page.
the file is exist.

it says: ENOENT: no such file or directory.

this is the code:

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url)

// Checking the extension 
let extName = path.extname(filePath)

// Content Type
let contentType = 'text/html'

// check ext and set ceontent type
switch (extName) {
    case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript'
        break
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css'
        break
    case '.json':
        contentType = 'application/json'
        break
    case '.png':
        contentType = 'image/png'
        break
    case '.jpg':
        contentType = 'image/jpg'
        break
}

console.log(contentType, "here")

// Read file
fs.readFile(filePath, (err,content) => {
    console.log(filePath)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        if (err.code == 'ENONET') {
            //Page not found
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '404.html'), (err,content) => {
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
                res.end(content, 'utf-8')
            })
        } else {
            // some server error
            res.writeHead(500)
            res.end(`Server Error ${err.code}`)
        }
    }else {
        // Success
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType})
        res.end(content,'utf-8')
    }
})
})

//creating the port either getting it from the host, or setting it to 5000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

// setting the server to listen on the port, and it get's also a call back so i print the server listens
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

I know that the problem is that I miss the extension in the filePath name.
but the thing is that the person I learn from, have the exact same code, and it works for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the problem is that I miss the extension in the filePath name. but the thing is that the person I learn from, have the exact same code, and it works for him.

This code could work only if the file `about` exists in the public directory (with no file extension on it).  So, rather than discuss how it worked for someone else, we should discuss how this code can work for you or what you would have to change in it to make it work for you.

Your code expects the path that is passed in the request to be an entire filename in your public directory.

So, when you send a request in for `/about`, you try to do `fs.readFile("about", ...)`.  That's the file that has to exist.

If you want `/about` to serve a file named `/about.html` in your file system, then you have check if `extName` is empty and, if so, add ".html" to the filename to give it a default extension.  Or, in some cases, you might check for more than one possibility in the file system.  If `about` isn't found, then check for `about.html`.

---

You could add a default `.html` path by changing this part:

```
// Checking the extension 
let extName = path.extname(filePath);
```

to this:

```
// Checking the extension 
let extName = path.extname(filePath);

if (!extName) {
    extName = ".html";
    filePath += ".html";
}
```

---

FYI, there's a misspelling too.  Change this:

```
if (err.code == 'ENONET')
```

to this:

```
if (err.code == 'ENOENT')
```

---

Another word of caution, your server may be vulnerable to some requests putting `../` into the path and then being able to access files outside of your `public` directory.  Most browsers will stop that, but scripted requests could do it.